# Programatically trigger form validation with JQuery Validator don't work

Tags: jquery-validate

According to the docs of jQuery Validator doing this should programatically trigger form validation.

```
var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.form();
```

But in my code it does nothing, why? I have a submit button on my form that is working fine, but validator.form() doesn't work at all. I've updated the post with my HTML form as well as the javascript code.
This is my form

```
<form class="kt-form kt-form--label-right" id="frm_sok" action="ajax/artikkel.php?a=sok_artikler" method="post">
    <div class="kt-portlet__body">
        <div class="kt-blog-post">
          <div class="form-group ">                     
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="form-control" type="search" value="{{ sok }}" id="searchinput" name="searchinput">
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                   <label>Ikke søk i :</label>
               <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="skjulnyheter" name="skjulnyheter">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="skjulnyheter">Nyheter</label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="skjulforum" name="skjulforum">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="skjulforum">Forum</label>
               </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                   <label for="sorter">Sorter:</label><br />
               <select class="form-control" name="sorter" id="sorter">
                  <option value="a.opp_dato DESC">Nyeste</option>
                  <option value="score">Beste treff</option>
                  <option value="a.opp_dato ASC">Eldste</option>
               </select>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kt-portlet__foot">
        <div class="kt-form__actions">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sokknapp" value="Søk" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$( window ).on( 'load', function() 
{
   var validator = $("#frm_sok").validate(
   {
       rules:
       {
        searchinput: 
        {
            required: true
        }                   
        },
        messages:
        {
            searchinput : 
            {
                required : 'Du må neste søke etter noe. Noe som helst. Ett eller annet.'
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) 
        {
            $('.error').css( "display", "inline-block !important");
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) 
        {
        preload_kamp();
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(
            {
                success: function(data) 
                {
                $( "#sokcontent" ).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });


   validator.form();

});
```

Comment: You put the `submitHandler` inside of the `rules` object so that's one huge problem right there.  And never use Allman code style on JavaScript.

Comment: I'm sorry, thats just a typo when editing the question. I've fixed it.

Comment: Why not show a concise working example that includes the relevant HTML?

Comment: Now you have the settings block inside a load event by itself. Where is the validator???

Comment: @Sparky that is true. Don't know why I struggle so much with pasting the code in. I'm sorry. Editet the question again.

Comment: What is `{% if sok %}` and do you know if `validator.form()` is even being rendered on the page when it loads?  Typically, for client-side programming issues, we focus on the client-side code being rendered in the browser.  Again, where is the rendered  HTML of the form?  If I wanted to help you, I'd have to recreate something from scratch.  Just enough code for a minimal, complete, verifiable example please!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example